# When clicked on card how we can turn over card on flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to allow my card to have two sides front/back. The thing is quite simple but tricky for flex layout. Is it even possible to put this kind of logic on flex layout?
How can we manage that?

Here is my code snippet
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/lukes8/pen/wvXLbWz?editors=1100) .
Here is sample for two sided effect how it could look like
[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Ossoona/pen/GJmvmJ?editors=0100)

```css
main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.single-box {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: center;
  width: 270px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
}

.header-area.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSjNSVKfWJh2gqMd3ClC-pfA8MX9X34oOP8rX-psZvYcNrrZA2l1AGCP_mIG0MVZl6hj6A&usqp=CAU);
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-area {
  background-size: cover;
  /* padding: 100px 30px; */
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 50% 0;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); */
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .3s;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.header-area.img1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.body-area {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="single-box">
    <div class="header-area img1"></div>
    <div class="body-area">
      <h3>Banana</h3>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-box">
    <div class="header-area img1"></div>
    <div class="body-area">
      <h3>Banana</h3>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approch the issue as following:

add a level of hiearachy in your html to avoid any issue when flipping the card.

To use youre structure it would be:

```
<main> <!-- flex container -->
  <div class="single-box"><!-- flex child -->
    <div class="single-box_inner"><!-- actual item that flip -->
        <!-- rest of the code -->
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="single-box"><!-- flex child -->
    <div class="single-box_inner"><!-- actual item that flip -->
        <!-- rest of the code -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ussing this structure, you then have to force a minimal size for each `.single-box` to avoid any deformation during flipping, but with zero design rules (background color, border, ...), this is just a structural bloc.
Then you can design the `.single-box_inner` as you want (there will be the actual cards).

Then you just need to toggle the class using a little bit of JS (if you need to flip on click like your first link), and handle the animation with CSS.

Hope it helps.